# Custom GridView selector color overflows or moves or is being dragged when I scroll

Tags: android, gridview

I have a Gridview with a custom adapter. Everything is working fine but when I select a child of gridview and scroll down, the selector color is being dragged down, like an overflow. I tried using a custom selector but it didnt help.

GridView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/popup_layout"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/llayout1"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_design">

        <TextView
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/textView6" 
            android:layout_weight="7" 
            android:textSize="16sp" 
            android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_style"
            android:id="@+id/prototypeName"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/llayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/llayout1"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_design">
    <TextView
        android:text="Orientation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
</LinearLayout>
<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/llayout2"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:id="@+id/createGrid"
    android:listSelector="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

Screenshots:

1. Child selected
   [image: Selected child]

2.Scrolling down after selection. (Top left corner, color is being dragged)
[image]

Any help appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should store position of selected item in some variable inside adapter. So you can change background color depends on this variable.
Could you attach code of your adapter?

Comment: hey! How can i get selected item inside adapter? I have an onItemClickListener() in my activity and I tried setting the background from there and to my surprise, there is no color drag. But now if i select the first child and scroll down, I see one more child is selected and i scroll back up, the previously selected item has changed. Then I added a for loop in onItemClickListener to set all other views to transparent, but still I see a selection when i scroll. Thank you for the response!

Comment: This happens because GridView items are reusing. You should change color of background inside method getView(..) in your adapter depends on position param.

One more proposal: try to use RecyclerView. GridView and ListView outdated.